# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, init

Trying to make a QR code generator for each instance creation, I get this error:**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save'

Could anyone tell me the problem with my code or maybe a better way to go about generating QR codes per model?

I've tried including the qr code generation within the methods as well.

```
from django.db import models
import qrcode

# Create your models here.
class Attendee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        box_size=15,
        border=5
        )
    data = 'http://localhost:8000/attendees/confirmation/'
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    s = img.save('C:/Users/Storm/Projects/QRAttendance/attendees/static/images/QR1.png')
    # save = img.save('QR_'+str(first_name)+'_'+str(last_name)+'.png')

    def __init__(self, data, img, qrcode, qr, s):
        self.s = s

    def __str__(self):
        fullname = '{0.last_name}, {0.first_name}, {0.present}'
        return fullname.format(self)
```

The current error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 73, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 513, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

Comment: Please show how the line that is causing the error - you probably instantiate ``Attendee`` in it.

Comment: **It shows a couple of line errors but it really probably is just line 21 to 22 with "def __init__" function**

  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 73, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "C:\Users\Storm\Envs\QRAttendance\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 513, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save'

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this traceback. Did you already store an instance of ``Attendee``, then change its definition?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi okay so I've made new edits, including some edits I made for the script itself. please check it out. I am trying to create a QR code for each instance of an Attendee created. Putting the img.save inside the method reads it as a string.

Comment: You get the error from *loading* existing data from the database. You already have stored instances in there with a different version of the class. This has nothing to do with handling the QR code, and everything with django models.

Comment: Yes QR generation works well.. but I am also trying to figure out how I could get the img.save function into the __init__. removing the s positional argument comes back with the s undefined. could you help with that?